# count comments for each row Union and Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

See sample data below.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
    table1.stuff, 
    COUNT(table1.id) AS row_count, 
    COUNT(comment_table.id) AS comment_count 

FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN comment_table 
        ON table1.id = comment_table.page_id 
            AND comment_table.page_type = 'nofun'

UNION 

SELECT 
    table2.stuff, 
    COUNT(table2.id) AS row_count, 
    COUNT(comment_table.id) AS comment_count 

FROM table2 
    LEFT JOIN comment_table 
        ON table2.id = comment_table.page_id 
            AND comment_table.page_type = 'fun'
```

Sample data table1:

```
id     stuff
1      the stuff
2      other stuff
```

Sample data table2:

```
id     stuff
1      the stuff still
2      other stuff still
```

Sample data comment_table:

```
id     page_id     page_type     comment 
5      1           fun           Ello
6      2           nofun         hey janis
```

Desired Results:

```
stuff              comment_count    row_count
the stuff still    1                2
other stuff        1                0
```

logic of sample data:
I would like to return all rows from table1 and table2. I would also like to get the total number of comments from comment_table associated with each row from table1 and table2 and lastly, count the total number of row returned from table1 and table2.

table1 and table2 have a "page_type", in this case table1 is "nofun" and table2 is "fun". Each comment_table row is related to either table1 or table2 by it's "page_type" AND "page_id", row id of either table1 or table2.

table1 id:2 has one comment (comment_table id:6) and table2 id:1 has one comment (comment_table id:5).

The desired results table shows two sample rows with 'stuff' from table1 and table2 and also the comment count for each row, and a total number of rows.

I do not believe I am wholly understanding the left join. How can I accomplish my goal.?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What is the correlation between your sample data and expected output. Please elaborate the logic further in the question

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Your desired result does not match the sample data nor your description. Where does "blah blah" manifest from? It is not part of your sample data. *"I would like to return all rows from table1 and table2"* Where can we see that? Where does "row_count" comes from? I do not see either a comment, a table-id or a table row where you have something with count 2 and something with count 0. Also, you probably want to add a `group_by` if you use a `count` (although I am not sure what you are grouping by).

Comment: Generally: if you have pages of 2 different types, put them in one table and add a column "page_type" for it. Then adding a page type is as simple as finding a 3rd word for it, and you do not need to add a new table and modify every query you have (e.g. adding another union).

Comment: @Solarflare, thank you for taking a look. I've corrected the desired results data above (it was getting late and I should have waited to post). The "row_count" is in each select above and in the desired results the "row_count" is 2 because two rows were returned. Please let me know if I can add anything to clarify anything that is unclear..

Answer (score 0):

BIG thanks to @Solarflare for pointing out the lack of GROUP BY.

Here is what I needed:

```
SELECT 
    `table1`.`stuff`, 
    COUNT(`comment_table`.`id`) AS comment_count 

FROM `table1` 
    LEFT JOIN `comment_table` 
        ON `table1.id` = `comment_table`.`page_id` 
            AND `comment_table`.`page_type` = 'nofun' 
GROUP BY `table1`.`id`

UNION 

SELECT 
    `table2`.`stuff`, 
    COUNT(`comment_table`.`id`) AS comment_count 
FROM `table2` 
    LEFT JOIN `comment_table` 
        ON `table2`.`id` = `comment_table`.`page_id` 
            AND `comment_table`.`page_type` = 'fun'
GROUP BY `table2`.`id`
```

Data Results:

```
stuff              comment_count
the stuff still    1
other stuff        1
```

I removed "row_count" since the data is properly grouped I can get the total row count from $page->num_rows.

Thank you everyone who took their time to view my question and certainly those who took the time to comment.